# Vagrant virtual machine automatically halting when laptop is put to sleep

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I’m using a Vagrant box (running in VirtualBox) I got from a third party and it always automatically shuts down when I put my MacBook Pro to sleep. When I wake up my laptop I need to run `vagrant up` to get the machine running again and its logs appear to report a normal shutdown. Other Vagrant boxes on my other MacBook Pro work fine and stay up while my laptop sleeps.

How does the automatic halting of Vagrant work? How do I turn it off?

Version information if it helps:

- Vagrant 1.7.2
- VirtualBox 4.3.22
- VM `uname -a` is `Linux vagrant 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)
- Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2

Comment: My other laptop is of the same generation but a 13". The VMs are Ubuntu rather than Debian. As I said I haven't found any reference to this searching on Google and I've looked through both the instance Vagrantfile and the Vagrantfile in `~/.vagrant.d/` and don't see anything pertaining to this.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here.

Comment: I've got vagrant 1.7.2 on OS X 10.10.2 and 13" 2014 MBP Retina and when it goes to sleep my vagrant default aborts. Current machine states:

default                   aborted (virtualbox)

The VM is in an aborted state. This means that it was abruptly
stopped without properly closing the session. Run `vagrant up`
to resume this virtual machine. If any problems persist, you may
have to destroy and restart the virtual machine. Shouldn't these catch the sleep event and suspend?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem; updating to VirtualBox 4.3.24 solved the problem for me.
Further reference:

- Vagrant 1.7.2
- Mac OS X 10.10.2

Comment: Just updated to **Virtualbox 4.3.26** - https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads and also solved the issue for me. Same versions as @Markus and thanks for the solution: - Vagrant 1.7.2 - http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html - Mac OS X 10.10